# How to reference an externally-defined constant in Angular2 template file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a bunch of string constants defined in a separate `constants.ts` file like this
`export const MY_PLACEHOLDER: string = 'some placeholder';`

I need to use `MY_PLACEHOLDER` in the template file of an Angular2 component like so
`<input ... [placeholder]=MY_PLACEHOLDER />`

Right now I just import the constant in `my-component.ts` file like this
`import {MY_PLACEHOLDER} from './constants'` and then use it in the template file.

This works fine, except for every constant I do this with, I get a tslint warning `unused property "MY_PLACEHOLDER"`.

How can I use/reference the external constant in my template file in a way that would avoid this warning?

EDIT: I know I can turn off the tslint warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should assign the constant property to some component level variable and use that in the template.

Comment: Yes, that would do it.  Except I don't want to pollute my components with constant string definitions.  The constants may be shared by more than one component, they might have to be translated, etc.

Comment: That's correct, I am saying we may create a variable in component like `someVar = constants.MY_PLACEHOLDER;` so you don't have to define string and it may be used at multiple places. However if you want to use them directly in the UI without declaring in component, you may create a Service which returns your constants, but that seems to be over kill.

Comment: I think the variable would trigger the same tslint warning ('unused variable'), wouldn't it? WRT the service, how would I consume its output in the template?

Comment: It should not, unused variable is for import statement.

Comment: I just tried that.  Even the variable gives me the 'unused property' tslint warning.

Comment: Although not ideal, using the component variable preceded by this line `// tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-variable` seems like an acceptable solution.